# Does microsoft sharepoint provide APIs to enable custom UI to built on top of sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

A client's employee base is struggling with using sharepoint UI as an interface. As a result the client is evaluating the option of building a custom UI on top of sharepoint to provide a better user experience; [The other option being to move away completely from sharepoint (non trivial, high cost option)]

My research indicates that you can customize the UI look and feel (but the client is looking for much more).

Another option appears to be to change/improve the experience by building PowerApps

The option I have been trying to assess,is to see if sharepoint provides adequate set of APIs/integration interfaces that allows the user to build a completely independent UI and user experience. Its effort intensive ofcourse, and feels like reinventing the wheel, and am wondering about whether others have faced similar UX callenges, and what possible solutions they might have evaluated, and path they have gone ahead with.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint 2013+ or for SharePoint 2007 or 2010? From 2007 onwards you have web services, and calls to these libraries are optimized in client-side JS libraries like [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/). Beginning with the 2013 version there is a quite useful [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/fp142380.aspx) which allows for most operations imaginable.

Comment: Sharepoint 2013+

Answer (score 0):

Under the covers, SharePoint is a SQL database and a collection of .NET classes that define each SharePoint object: SPWeb, SPSite, SPWeb, SPList, SPUser list item, document etc. Most of these objects are exposed via web services. Microsoft then built an IIS/ASP.NET based UI for the out of box user experience. There are mobile apps that are not browser based that call the SharePoint REST services to read and update lists and libraries. If you wanted to, you could built your own complete UI based on just about any technology. Is it worth it? Probably not. There are many customization options available, depending on your version of SharePoint.

(If I could post comments... :-) I would then ask: Tell us more about what the users need in the UI that is not supplied by out of the box SharePoint.)

Comment: thanks Mike. Sharepoint UI is very comprehensive. The concern is not around users needs not being met, but about users finding the sharepoint ui experience overwhelming or confusing, and they dont seem to be too eager to log on to the portal.